# How to remove Knockout.js ObservableArray-object after ajax call

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I'm trying to remove an object from an ObservableArray after an ajax-call. It works with the '.pop' function, but not when I'm using the custom knockout.js '.remove'-function.

If I move the call to the '.remove' function outside the ajax-complete function, '.remove' does work. But I would really rather have it inside the '.complete'.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

This doesn't work:

self.removeItem = function(data) {

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: null
    }).complete(function (item,data)  {
             self.Items.remove(data);
    });
};
```

I made a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/6oe6dn7n/1/

My view-model looks like so:

```
var data = {
  Name: "Test",
  Items: ["One", "Two", "Three"]    
};

function ViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
   self.Items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Items,   

function(item) {
    return { value: ko.observable(item) };
}));

self.removeItem = function(data) { 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: null
    }).complete(function (item,data)  {
             // This doesn't affect the observableArray.
             // 'self.Items.pop(data) does, however.
             self.Items.remove(data);
    });
};
}
```

And my HTML looks like so:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTemplate', foreach: Items     }"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="itemTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value: value" />
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">Remove     Item</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have replaced "data" variable object in the context of response handler:

was:

```
self.removeItem = function(data) { // <- data
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: null
    }).complete(function (item, data)  { // <- another data overrides upper data
             // This doesn't affect the observableArray.
             // 'self.Items.pop(data) does, however.
             self.Items.remove(data); // <- what data to use???
    });
};
```

changed:

```
self.removeItem = function(data) { 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: null
    }).complete(function (item, data1)  { // another data - data1
             // This doesn't affect the observableArray.
             // 'self.Items.pop(data) does, however.
             self.Items.remove(data);
    });
};
```

I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6oe6dn7n/3/), it works for me - at least removes items.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the data variable that is passed into removeItem. Instead you override it, by using the textStatus variable of the complete callback. Like so:

```
self.removeItem = function(data) { 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: null
    }).complete(function (item)  {
             self.Items.remove(data);
    });
};
```

The reason self.Items.pop(data) worked is because .pop doesn't actually take any parameters. So the data you passed in is never used, and the call is just popping the array.  The second parameter in the complete callback method is by default a textStatus response.

From the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> **complete**
>   Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )
>   A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").